# computing the heat kernel for small times

Tags: partial-differential-equations, computational-geometry, heat-equation

The heat kernel on a two-dimensional manifold $M$ has the well-known expression

$$H(p,q,t) = \sum_{i=1}^\infty e^{\lambda_i t}\phi_i(p)\phi_i(q)$$
where $\phi_i, \lambda_i$ are the eigenfunctions and eigenvalues of the Laplace-Beltrami operator on $M$.

This expression reveals the fact that for *large* times, the behavior of the low-magnitude eigenvalue eigenfunctions determine the value of the heat kernel.

Unfortunately the above formula is impractical for computing $H$ for *small* values of $t$: the formula becomes increasingly dependent on the high-frequency eigenfunctions, which are hard to compute stably.

Is there an alternative formula that can be used for $t$ near zero?

Comment: Yes, of course, this is very well known. You should look at the references related to spectral geometry (can you hear the shape of the drum, determinants of Laplacians, etc.). I am curious how you are (numerically?) computing the eigenvalues of the Laplacian?

Comment: @user226970 : maybe for $t$ very small it is better to approximate the (diffusion) differential equation directly, than to decompose it spectrally in term of modes (eigenfunctions) ?

Comment: @user1952009 Yes absolutely, this is exactly what is done in those reference.

Comment: @user226970 sounds interesting, can you elaborate? I'm aware of some of the results of Weyl, Kac, Minakshisundaram, etc on the asymptotics of $H(q,q,t)$ as $t\to 0$ but I'd be interested in references that look at computational aspects

Comment: @user1952009 Right, I can solve the heat equation using finite elements, to get an estimate of $H(p,q,t)$. My concern with this approach would be how to properly discretize time, the manifold $M$ near $p$, and the Dirac delta initial condition, so that the numerical error is bounded. But maybe it's all straightforward...